# Manipulating multiple arrays with multiple criteria

Tags: arrays, ruby

```
a = [nil, nil, 40, 30]
b = [nil, 20, nil, 50]
```

I want to: Compare a & b. If both positions are nil, set them equal to 0. If one is nil, set it equal to the non-nil #. If both are non-nil, set leave them as is.

In other words, I'm looking for this result:

```
a = [0, 20, 40, 30]
b = [0, 20, 40, 50]
```

Thank you!

Edit: Clarify, if both are non-nil, then return them as is. Bad example to leave this case out, so I edited it above.

Comment: What should happen, when both arrays are not nil?

Comment: @spickermann Sorry, When both are array, just leave them as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nil || x` will yields `x` (because `nil` is falsy value is ruby)

```
nil || 2   # fallback to second value if the first value is `nil`
# => 2
nil || nil || 0  # fallback to 0 if both values are 0
# => 0
2 || nil  # Use the first value
# => 2
```

Using such characteristic, you can do something like:

```
a = [nil, nil, 40, nil, -1]
b = [nil, 20, nil, nil, 2]

a, b = a.zip(b).map { |x, y| [x||y||0, y||x||0] }.transpose
# a => [0, 20, 40, 0, -1]
# b => [0, 20, 40, 0, 2]
```

Comment: love the use of the zip function! did not know about that one.

Comment: This is working as I hoped, even despite me forgetting to clarify what happens when they're both non-nil. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would start with:

```
a = [nil, nil, 40, nil]
b = [nil, 20, nil, nil]

a = a.zip(b).map { |pair| pair.map(&:to_i).max }
b = a.dup

a #=> [0, 20, 40, 0]
b #=> [0, 20, 40, 0]
```

Explanation: `zip` builds an array of pairs, `to_i` translates `nil` to `0`. I am not sure about the `max`, because you didn't define what to return if both arrays are not `nil` at a certain index.

Answer (score 1):

I guess someone should give a conventional solution that doesn't make use of the `nil.to_i #=> 0` "trick". Note that if an element of either array is not `nil`, it will not be changed.

```
def modify(arr, other)
  arr.each_index { |i| arr[i] = (other[i].nil? ? 0 : other[i]) if arr[i].nil? }
  arr
end

a = [nil, nil, 40, 30]
b = [nil, 20, nil, 50]

modify a,b
  #=> [0, 20, 40, 30] 
modify b,a
  #=> [0, 20, 40, 50] 

a #=> [0, 20, 40, 30] 
b #=> [0, 20, 40, 50]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a.each_with_index.map { |val,i| [val.to_i,b[i].to_i].max }
=> [0, 20, 40, 0]
```

`nil.to_i` returns 0, and that is a really cool thing because then you are comparing two similar things and you don't have to do a nil check which is a common code smell.

UPDATE: looking at the use of the `zip` method in one of the other answers:

```
a.zip(b).map {|a,b| [a.to_i, b.to_i].max }
```

Is a bit more elegant. for more info about `zip` see http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/zip